# How to append to href in link tag?

Tags: javascript, html

These are my `<link>` tags

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href= "javascript:x+'/resources/media/logo-top24x24.ico';">
<link rel="footer icon" href= "javascript:x+'/resources/media/logo-bottom24x24.ico';">
```

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myserver.com/base.js"></script>
```

Problem is I'm not getting the .ico. In console, it shows  `javascript:x` as it is and not getting replaced by the url which I've written in base.js.

Content of base.js

```
var x = "http://www.mysite.com";
```

and nothing else (with the usual html syntax)

Any help appreciated!!

P.S: When i use `<a>` tag `javascript:x` gets replaced with the URL in base.js.

P.S2: I've got several `<link>` tags and want to append to each of them. Post Edited.

Comment: so it from  serverside

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/media/logo-top24x24.ico" id="foo">
```

And JS:

```
var x    = "http://www.mysite.com";
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
var href = elem.getAttribute('href');

elem.setAttribute('href', x + '/' + href);
```